# Why does Panner node default to hard-right position on Chrome?

Tags: web-audio-api

I set the panner to:

```
panner.setPosition(0,0,0);
```

If I open it up in Firefox it does what you would expect - centers the input source and places it in the middle of the stereo field.

In Chrome it does not do this and the audible default output is panned  *hard-right*.

Why? .... and is this a bug ?

I am on Linux Mint OS btw.